# Changing Mergin Maps workspace name

Tags: mergin-maps

I am managing a Mergin Maps field app for a local non-profit, for which we have been granted a free subscription.

The account has a single Workspace, and I would like to change that Workspace's name.  However, I have not found a way to do this.  The [Mergin Maps documentation](https://merginmaps.com/docs/manage/workspaces/) states that *"Every workspace is tied to a subscription."*, but there is no information on how to modify the Workspace name.  An internet search came up empty.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workspace name is used as unique identifier in the API and therefore it is not possible to change it at the moment.